# How to fix Conda environment stuck in portrait mode from Mac Video Effects?

Tags: python, macos, opencv, anaconda, conda

I'm experiencing an unexpected issue while using OpenCV in a Conda environment on my Mac. When I run my OpenCV code in this environment, my video output is blurred as if a "portrait" mode (background blur) is enabled. This happens even when the camera effects on my Mac are turned off. The blurring issue does not occur when running the same code using a regular Python environment outside of Conda.

This problem started after I had used the Mac's video background blur effect for a video call, but persisted in the Conda environment even after turning the effect off. The effect does not persist when using the regular Python interpreter, only in the Conda environment.

I have stripped down my code and just opening my camera with OpenCV, and the issue persists.

Here is the code (although this should not affect it):

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    cv2.imshow('Webcam', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I have tried various troubleshooting steps, including creating a new Conda environment, updating all packages, rebooting my system, and checking for interferences from other applications, but none of these have solved the issue.

Does anyone know why this might be happening and how I can prevent the background blur when using OpenCV in a Conda environment?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Maybe try deleting the OpenCV in the package cache then create a new environment. I’d also be looking for environment variables.